# How can I get the image name currently being displayed by Slick?

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

I've got a question that might seem pretty simple or stupid, but I'm a kind of new to this thing so...

I need to get the image name (filename) of the picture that is currently being displayed in the carousel (created with Slick). There's a carousel showing the only one image at a time and containing let's say 7 images.

Could you please advise?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `afterChange` event, you can track the active slide right after the transition is made. Then $(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)) gives the whole slide element where we try to find the image ant it's src attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  slide: 'div',
  cssEase: 'linear'
});

$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
//Here I do split the `src` attribute value because I'm using an absolute path.
// $(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)) gives the whole slide 
    var CurrentImg=$(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)).find('img').attr('src').split('/').pop();
console.log(CurrentImg)
});

});
```

```css
img{
width:200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/Wikipedia-logo_ka.png">Wiki</div>
  <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/HTML5_oval_logo.png">Html5</div>
  <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/b/bb/SoundCloud_logo.png">SoundCloud</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Bilel! Thanks so much for your detailed answer and the code - everything works perfectly! :-)

Comment: What about if I never touch the slider and then the event is never fired? How can I access it OUTSIDE of any event?

Comment: @ZioBit please clarify the question :) If you run my code, you will see that you don't need to touch the slider it's just tracking the transition here. Are you expecting to define a custom callback for a specific event ? Like here : https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/197

Comment: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick at the bottom of this page you can find Slick events and Methods.